# Chrome book optical disk drive

Tags: 12.04, chromebook

I don't know if this is the right place to ask (if it is not then if someone would guide me to the correct place) but I want to buy a chrome book and I found out that there is no way to get an external optical drive to work.  I found a video on how to install ubuntu on chromebook but my question is that will an external optical drive work on Ubuntu that is installed on the chromebook?  Or will it not play like in chromeos?

Thanks Goku.

Comment: Close voter(s): This is asking what *Ubuntu* is capable of. I can see a possible argument for closing this as *not constructive* or even--though I'd disagree with this--*too localized*, this is on-topic and ultimately answerable (and I've posted a CW answer). It probably doesn't need to be closed at all.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking further into the question of whether or not you can get the external optical drive to work in ChromeOS. **As for Ubuntu**, an external USB optical drive, like USB drives in general, *should* work without problems. To test this, create an Ubuntu live USB stick, boot a Chromebook from it, and see if the external optical drive works. (Don't install Ubuntu; instead select *Try Ubuntu without installing* and see if it can recognize the external optical drive.)

If you don't already have a Chromebook, you might or might not be able to persuade the staff of a store to let you test this. But since a Chromebook doesn't appear easily to do what you want it to do, this might not be the best computer for you.

Ultimately, USB *drives* of any kind *usually* work on Ubuntu without any problems, on any computer (so long as you can run Ubuntu on it). There is no 100% guarantee, however.